# Mysql Slave not updating

Tags: mysql, replication

I have replication set up every thing looks fine I have not errors , but the data is not being moved to the Slave

```
mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                Master_Host: xxxxx
                Master_User: xxxxxx
                Master_Port: xxxx
              Connect_Retry: 30
            Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
        Read_Master_Log_Pos: 98
             Relay_Log_File: xxxxx-relay-bin.002649
              Relay_Log_Pos: 235
      Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
           Slave_IO_Running: Yes
          Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
            Replicate_Do_DB:
        Replicate_Ignore_DB:
         Replicate_Do_Table:
     Replicate_Ignore_Table:
    Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                 Last_Errno: 0
                 Last_Error:
               Skip_Counter: 0
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 98
            Relay_Log_Space: 235
            Until_Condition: None
             Until_Log_File:
              Until_Log_Pos: 0
         Master_SSL_Allowed: No
         Master_SSL_CA_File:
         Master_SSL_CA_Path:
            Master_SSL_Cert:
          Master_SSL_Cipher:
             Master_SSL_Key:
      Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Were you able to get the replication working Mindking?

Answer (score 3):

Run a `show master status` or `show master status\G` on the master DB. It will give you the correct values to update your slave with.

From your slave status, it looks like your slave has successfully connected to the master and is awaiting log events. To me, this means your slave user has been properly set up, and has the correct access. It really seems like you just need to sync the correct log file position.

Careful, because to get a good sync, you should probably stop the master, dump the DB, record the master log file positions, then start the master, import the DB on the slave, and finally start the slave in slave mode using the correct master log file pos. I've done this about 30 times, and if you don't follow those steps almost exactly, you *will* get a bad sync.

Comment: after fiddling around quite a bit with my first replication setup, i can recommend to new users to do a `RESET MASTER` and a `RESET SLAVE` before a new setup attempt.

Answer (score 1):

there could be couple of issues

1. master did not know about slave.
2. slave and master are not in sync with relay log file.

you have to sync the slave with master from where it did not updated. then you start slave. it should work fine.